# Understanding how a Sed script breaks down into individual commands

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

I'm new to `sed`, can you tell me what the following does? I can't find a complete regex in the command from below.

`sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/>[[:space:]]*\n/>\\\n/g' nlTest1.txt > nlTest2.txt`

Are we having 3 commands together?

`:a;N;$!ba;s`

`>[[:space:]]*\n`

`>\\\n/g`

Or I'm not intrepreting the command correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The partitioning of the commands is:

- `:a;N;$!ba`, which is a common idiom for reading the entire input file into the pattern space (buffer to operate on) at once, in a loop; it is composed of 3 `;`-separated commands:

  - label `:a` (defines a script location that can be jumped to)
  - function `N` (reads the next line and appends it to the pattern space)
  - `$! ba`, which branches (`b`) to label `a`, if the input line is not (`!`) the *last* (`$`) one.
- `s/>[[:space:]]*\n/>\\\n/g` is a regular `s` function call in the form `s/<regex>/<substitution-string>/`; here, all occurrences of a `>` followed by any run of whitespace followed by a newline are replaced with just `>\` and a newline.